# Primes dividing consecutive composites

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes

[Grimm's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_conjecture) states that, for any set of consecutive composite numbers \$n+1, n+2, ..., n+k\$, there exist \$k\$ distinct primes \$p_i\$, such that \$p_i\$ divides \$n+i\$ for each \$1 \le i \le k\$.

For example, take \$\{24, 25, 26, 27, 28\}\$. We can see that if we take the primes \$2, 5, 13, 3, 7\$, each composite number is divisible by at least one of the primes:

$$
2 \mid 24 \quad 5 \mid 25 \quad 13 \mid 26 \\
3 \mid 27 \quad 7 \mid 28
$$

Note that it doesn't matter that \$26\$ is also divisible by \$2\$, so long as, for each composite number, there is a corresponding prime that divides it. For the purposes of this challenge, we'll assume Grimm's conjecture is true.

Given a list of \$n\$ consecutive composite integers \$C\$, in any reasonable format, return a list of \$n\$ distinct prime numbers \$P\$ such that, for each \$c\$ in \$C\$, there is a corresponding \$p\$ in \$P\$ such that \$c\$ is divisible by \$p\$. You may return any such list in any order, and in any reasonable format.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[4] -> [2]
[6] -> [2]
[8, 9, 10] -> [2, 3, 5]
[12] -> [2]
[14, 15, 16] -> [7, 3, 2]
[18] -> [2]
[20, 21, 22] -> [2, 3, 11]
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28] -> [2, 5, 13, 3, 7]
[30] -> [2]
[32, 33, 34, 35, 36] -> [2, 11, 17, 5, 3]
[38, 39, 40] -> [2, 3, 5]
[42] -> [2]
[44, 45, 46] -> [2, 3, 23]
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52] -> [2, 7, 5, 3, 13]
[54, 55, 56, 57, 58] -> [2, 5, 7, 3, 29]
[60] -> [2]
[62, 63, 64, 65, 66] -> [31, 3, 2, 5, 11]
[68, 69, 70] -> [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Brownie points for beating my 10 byte, brute force Jelly answer

Comment: Can we output multiple sets of primes, or just one?

Comment: @emanresuA You may output any number of sets of primes that satisfy the requirements

Answer (score 11):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcy9DcJADEDhhV5x57/c7cAGUXokFIGEMgAMQc0UFJQMwBAscsSFLUufno/b9TQ@r/V3v43f430@bN/nehljzLMtzLFPo1PLflTJZVSnJtS2LylIRZLEEEcCmZA0zUoFVdRQRzPThnYszTIzwxxLsoZ1vOAVT3PDHQ98wvNlZBZCKGGEE9lFIzpTWZY/)

```
     mp  -- prime factors of each number
    Π    -- cartesian product of this list of lists
►        -- find the element that maximizes:
 oLu     --   (2 functions composed) the length of the unique values
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
vǏΠ'Þu
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ2x4/OoCfDnnUiLCIiLCJbMjQsMjUsMjYsMjcsMjhdIl0=)

Similar to ovs' answer. Outputs a list of lists of primes.

```
vǏ     # Prime factors of each
  Π    # Cartesian product
   '   # Filter by
    Þu # All unique
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ÆfŒpQƑƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rRSQWBxyYea/8fbWSiY2SqY2SmY2SuY2QRe7j9PwA)

Are brownie points redeemable for actual brownies? Similar to ovs' answer and my Vyxal answer.

Returns a bunch of duplicates because Jelly has no 'distinct prime factors' builtin.

```
Æf      Prime factors
  Œp    Cartesian product of all
      Ƈ Filter by
     Ƒ  Remains same under
    Q   Uniquify
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ḋᵐ∋ᵐ.d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7odbJzzqAJF6Kf//Rxua6Bia6hiaxf6PAgA)

```
?ḋᵐ∋ᵐ.d.     # implicit input and output
?ḋᵐ          # prime decompositions of each number in the input
   ∋ᵐ.       # for each prime decomposition one number is in the output
     .d.     # and: the output without duplicates is still the output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 22 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
(⊢∩∪¨)∘,∘↑(∘.,/3∘pco¨)
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=Uy9Izld/1Dc1uVI9JS2vWB0A&c=03jUtehRx8pHHasOrdB81DFDB4gftU3UAFJ6OvrGQKogOR8oBQA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFQxMFQ1MFQzMFAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

-7 thanks to people on APLFarm. Requires `pco`. There is no `pco` on TryAPL, so you need Dyalog APL installed locally. Outputs all possibilities.

Comment: TIO has dfns/pco: https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=Uy9Izld/1Dc1uVI9JS2vWB0A&c=03jUtehRx8pHHasOrdB81DFDB4gftU3UAFJ6OvrGQKogOR8oBQA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFQxMFQ1MFQzMFAA&i=AwA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f

Comment: Extended, [17 bytes](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=Uy9Izld/1Dc1uVI9JS2vWB0A&c=e9Sx6tCKR72zH3WsfNS74lHHDB0gftQ20RhI6enoP@pd8qh37aOuRQA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFQxMFQ1MFQzMFAA&i=AwA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f): `∪¨⍛∩⍨∘,∘↑3∘.,/⍤⍭⊢`

Comment: Full program, [18 bytes](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=Uy9Izld/1Dc1uVI9JS2vWB0A&c=ASAA3/8o4oqi4oip4oiqwqgpLOKGkeKImC4sLzNwY2/CqOKOlQ&f=AwA&i=S@MyNFEwNFUwNAMA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f): `(⊢∩∪¨),↑∘.,/3pco¨⎕`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 54 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⟧ＦＥＡΦι∧›λ¹¬﹪ιλ«≔υη≔⟦⟧υＦΦι⬤ι∨⁼κμ﹪κμＦη¿¬№λκ⊞υ⁺λ⟦κ⟧»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LSgQxEEXX9lfUsgJx4eALXA2DiovR3ocswjzs0GVnTFJuxG@PVcEBA5dw63FusptC3qVArY1cJmQLzpuH4Zgy4Dac8GU5cUVj4SlSPWSMFtbLHp/zIaglC1fSfE0Vt2nPlHSATD/wPVysS4nvi2InoZ6t8xZYfY/5RybS6y3j4ycHKjhb@BD8H7q7Tu57k4F4BNTsTeKl6mNm7Z5/MhIXLbrZG0n7GcYcZWwTSkWWSmvOra4trG5Et6I70b337fKLfgE) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs all sets. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⟧
```

Start with the empty set for `k=0`.

```
ＦＥＡΦι∧›λ¹¬﹪ιλ«
```

For each input composite number, get its factors.

```
≔υη≔⟦⟧υ
```

Make a backup of the sets found so far.

```
ＦΦι⬤ι∨⁼κμ﹪κμ
```

For each prime factor of the current composite number, ...

```
Ｆη
```

... and for each set, ...

```
¿¬№λκ
```

... if the set doesn't have that prime factor yet, then...

```
⊞υ⁺λ⟦κ⟧
```

... record a new set that does.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Output the sets that managed to acquire a prime factor for each input composite.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 98 bytes

```javascript
f=(A,b=[],k=2,[n,...a]=A)=>n?k>n?0:n%k?f(A,b,k+1):!b.includes(k)&&f(a,[...b,k])||f([n/k,...a],b):b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLLboMwELz3K9xDI6y6gJ8kSDTKdyAfgECVEpmqaXvKv9MhQU2EU4lY2tPuPHbW78VPcag@dx9fL67b1n3fZMGGlVluWZsJljsWhmFhsw3NXt26RcWpe2rXzTDF2mdO08cy3Llq/72tD0FLF4smKFgOFNqWHo9NkLuoPdOwkqZlX3Xu0O3rcN@9BegqS6aPUhJFJBf2YTJr7phdMrJihMfWn2VEMqI9BBd2NjtX4Naoi6VxNjmx30As57OLGAwcJexN75z7EBgSMCQMCh7E0l4gg1F5QiYeUMbzfclBfiCCmASpNFciHIZ5chKTPhLnkLiHiu3Ma6g7rqHgR0FXmdvswjekYEjBkEbUGs61uFpl3GJIzQNqaGl0NYLWw@Ak6PH@K//z3hG0AZcBjYGYAan5C1ryM//5qP4/MNjLYK/k36D7Xw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 105 bytes

```ruby
->l,*r{(2..l[0]).map{|x|r.any?{|y|x%y<1}||r<<x};r.permutation(l.size).find{|c|c.zip(l).all?{|a,b|b%a<1}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc1BCsMgEADAr/QS0JAubQ9eatuHiAdNIwjGiklA4/p26wOGiYfOzbza9e2mMRbyAHDiJimsKhRMGEH5/CmYMQ2Z3yti5DzVZ4SwxPXY1W5/njjY7LlQMNZ/C844w2kDcRSUcx2rSaMeVOe1tnAxQoysR4xJ2f4)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
f˜Igã.ΔÙÖ*Q
```

Outputs one result.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/7fQcz/TDi/XOTTk88/A0rcD//6ONDHSMDHWMjGIB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Fcw9SgNhEIDhq4SU8iL7zd9@W@UM1ssWEaJYCQrCFrbWEoIg2KVKk0NkSyGH8CLrTjHDwMM7z6/b@6fd/DZu1qu/j/1qvRkvp/nh92d8nI6318PlPH2@TN/T183d/M7c9zbQxzKVjtIsR5FcRnFKQqnLkgYpSJIY4kggLZKmWamgihrqaGZa0Q5Ls8zMMMeSrGId3uAFT3PDHQ@8xfNlZBZCKGGEE9lFJTraZhj@AQ).

Could output all results for the same byte-count by replacing `.Δ` with `Ùʒ`, but it's much slower and times out for the larger test cases: [try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//2bLnElnw6PDmcqSw5nDlipR//9bMjAsMjEsMjJd) or [<s>don't</s> verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Fcw/SgNREIDxq4SU8hX75t@@rXIG62ULBROsBAVhC1trSSEE7KxsPERep7fIRTY7xQwDP755erm7f3xYXufddnN5P262u/n8s@z/v@ZD@26nv@P5t308t1P7vLld3ljG0SbGWKcyULr1KJLLKE5JKHVd0iEFSRJDHAmkR9I0KxVUUUMdzUwrOmBplpkZ5liSVWzAO7zgaW6444H3eL6MzEIIJYxwIruoxEDfTdMV).

A port of *@ovs*' [Husk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239833/52210) and [Brachylog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239846/52210) answers, as well as *@emanresuA*'s [Vyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239834/52210) and [Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239836/52210) answers, would be **13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** in 05AB1E... :/ Looks like 05AB1E draws the short straw (or I should say longest..) by far with this approach, primarily because there isn't a clean way to reduce-by-cartesian-product (which is `¯¸š.»â€˜`, 8 out of 13 bytes).

```
f¯¸š.»â€˜ʒDÙQ
```

Outputs all possible outputs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//2bCr8K4xaEuwrvDouKCrMucypJEw5lR//9bMjAsMjEsMjJd) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##Fcw9SgNhEIDhq4TUL7Lf/O23VRovkHrZwoCClYUQSJHGwgOkE2xMHUgr2G1Io7fIRdadYoaBh3deXh82z4/TdrdaLm7vh8VytZuexvP4ff26G38ux9vb6e/z93B/@VhPe6a@t4E@5ql0lGY@iuQyilMSSp2XNEhBksQQRwJpkTTNSgVV1FBHM9OKdliaZWaGOZZkFevwBi94mhvueOAtni8jsxBCCSOcyC4q0dE2w/AP).

**Explanation:**

```python
f             # Map each integer in the (implicit) input-list to an inner list of
              # its unique prime factors
 ˜            # Flatten this list of lists
  Ig          # Push the input-length
    ã         # Take the cartesian product
     .Δ       # Find the first result which is truthy for:
       Ù      #  Uniquify the list
        Ö     #  Check for each prime if it evenly divides the (implicit) inputs
              #  at the same positions (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
         *    #  Multiply each by the (implicit) inputs at the same positions
          Q   #  And check if it's equal to the (implicit) input-list
              # (after which the found list is output implicitly)
```

If the inner list we're filtering on becomes smaller in length than the input-list after the `Ù`, it'll stay that same smaller size at the `Ö` and `*`. At the `Q` after that however, this smaller list can never be equal to the input-list.

```python
f             # Map each integer in the (implicit) input-list to an inner list of
              # its unique prime factors
 ¯¸š          # Prepend [[]] at the front of this list
    .»        # Left-reduce it by:
      â       #  Cartesian product of two lists
       €˜     # After the reduce, flatten each inner list
         ʒ    # Filter it by:
          D   #  Duplicate the list
           Ù  #  Uniquify this copy
            Q #  And check if the lists are still the same
              # (after which the list of lists is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 51 bytes

```factor
[ [ factors ] map [ members ] product-map longest ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDNTsNADITveYp5AaKs13YSeADEpRfEqeqhhC1UIj9NtgdU9dnDpioxPs3sfh5Lc9g3sR/nt9eXzfMj2n38yofx2IYpP9x@JkzhdA5dExYV/9nE9R/nJmIYQ4w/aauLeMqyS4Y0FzCud6WrqlDDFat1ZJLhBM5QV62SCpADGUwMEpCCSpBx3pI9wXt4hhd4C/UVfA02ji2UGSxgg7kC15AC4iDGCUMEopASYsfVQpWgHspQgVqeVtAa5cJds3mLLf4q3qXih@Tb0L6Hm793@7C8f/fdZ5gidvPi8vkX)

### Explanation

- `[ factors ] map` Get the prime factors of each number in the input list.
- `[ members ] product-map` Get every combination of picking one thing from each list. But remove duplicates.
- `longest` Get the longest one.

```
                        ! { 14 15 16 }
[ factors ] map         ! { { 2 7 } { 3 5 } { 2 2 2 2 } }
[ members ] product-map ! {
                            { 2 3 }
                            { 7 3 2 }
                            { 2 5 }
                            { 7 5 2 }
                            { 2 3 }
                            { 7 3 2 }
                            { 2 5 }
                            { 7 5 2 }
                            { 2 3 }
                            { 7 3 2 }
                            { 2 5 }
                            { 7 5 2 }
                            { 2 3 }
                            { 7 3 2 }
                            { 2 5 }
                            { 7 5 2 }
                        }
longest               ! { 7 3 2 }
```